# Долгое открытие формы на Windows Server 2016

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-server-2016

```
var form = new MyForm(someargs);
//400 мс
form.ShowDialog();
...
private void myForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //4500 мс после form.ShowDialog() на Windows 2016

}
```

Между вызовом `form.ShowDialog()` и срабатыванием обработчика события Load `myForm_Load` проходит:

1. на Windows Server 2008R2 ~250мс
2. на Windows Server 2016   ~4500мс

Железо:

1. на Windows Server 2008R2 2.8x12 ГГц физический сервер
2. на Windows Server 2016   2.4x20 ГГц виртуальная машина на Hyper-V

Структура формы.
  `TableLayoutPanel` c `Dock==DockStyle.Fill`. На ней пару десятков `TextBox`, `ComboBox`, `Label` и т.п. Ещё две `Button`, и по одному `TabControl` и `DataGridView`. И пара экземпляров наследника UserControl.

Свойство `DoubleBuffered` формы равно `true`, пробовал `false` скорость не изменилась

Что там так долго происходит? Что можно проверить?

---

#### Обновление

Код обработчиков событий формы и пользовательских элементов управления, был отпрофилирован самописным профилировщиком на основе StopWatch. Удалось установить, что задержка возникает в два этапа. Каждый раз она возникает перед вызовом сеттера пользовательского свойства `SelectedValue` элемента управления. 
Кстати это свойство помечено, как bindable для класса с помощью `[System.ComponentModel.DefaultBindingProperty("SelectedValue")]`. Но что именно тратит время так и не известно.

---

#### Обновление 2

Найден виновник тормозов. Это `ComboBox` с очень большим количеством элементов в DataSource. Теперь у меня есть [МСВП](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
    ...
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form = new MyForm(); //  76мс 2008R2;  123мс 2016
        form.ShowDialog();       //1820мс 2008R2;12440мс 2016
    }
}

public class MyForm : Form
{        
    private readonly ComboBox myComboBox = new ComboBox();
    public MyForm()
    {
        var manyItems = Enumerable.Range(1, 66_000)
            .Select(t => new
            {
                Key = t,
                Value1 = t.ToString(),
                Value2 = t.ToString() + t.ToString()
            })
            .ToList();
        myComboBox.DataSource = manyItems;
        myComboBox.ValueMember = "Key";
        myComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value2";
        this.Controls.Add(myComboBox);
    }
}
```

Comment: Конструктор формы проверить на наличие долгих операций.

Comment: @rdorn форма сконструирована уже. Тормоз между `ShowDialog` и `myForm_Load` где нет ни моего кода, ни генерированного конструктором. Или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: [ассоциация](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509053/showdialog-takes-too-much-time-on-windows-server-2016)

Comment: Или возьмите профайлер, и поищите узкое место напрямую, или убирайте контролы пока тормоза не пройдут. Судя по датагриду - вы вполне можете там за данными лезть, и это просто занимает дольше на одной машине, чем на второй.

Comment: @PashaPash, какой профайлер взять? Я уже написал свой профайлер не основе StopWatch, и использовал профилировщик производительности в Visual Studio 2017 Community. Второй мне дал не больше информации чем в вопросе - он показывает `ShowDialog` красным, а если в него перейти показывает некую `System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll`, но уже никакого кода. Самописным удалось установить, что задержка состоит из двух предположительно равных этапов по 2с небольшим секунды. Но откуда они вызываются всё ещё не ясно.

Comment: @PashaPash Рекомендованный вами метод удаления тоже был опробован. И оказалось что виноваты два экземпляра кастомного `UserControl` чей код тоже отпрофилирован...

Comment: @4per копайте дальше - раз юзер контролы - значит виноват какой-то код в них. Кроме вас, без доступа к коду, никто проблему не поймает и не починит.

Comment: @PashaPash, я это уже понял, что кроме меня никто. Но хотя бы, наводки не помешали бы..

Comment: Как предположили на en.so, могут быть виноваты обработчики событий контролов. Нужно поменять порядок загрузки данных и подписки на события: сперва data binding, потом подписка на события.

Comment: Пользователь будет выбирать из 66000 элементов? Может, предоставить юзеру возможность поиска по каким-то параметрам и выводить только отфильтрованные элементы. Или, как вариант, вместо комбобокса взять DataGridView в виртуальном режиме.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, пользователю приходилось выбирать из 9000 элементов (: Чтобы выйти на соответствующую задержку в примере пришлось немного поднять это кол-во. Да, безусловно придётся изменять дизайн формы, теперь. Но понять проблему тоже охота.

Comment: Вот ещё что: нужно сперва задать `DisplayMember`, а потом `DataSource`. Иначе комбобокс дважды заполняется.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да, конечно. Но конструктор пуля по сравнению с `ShowDialog`